# ASP.NET CORE Add easily accessible properties to logged user

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In our Asp.Net Core (2.2) MVC project we had to use an existing database (including all user & role related tables) from our previous Asp.Net Web app project.

Retrieving user data in asp.net web app (and having it available throughout the website) was preatty simple: upon login fill a custom user class/object with all the properties you need, save it as a Session variable and you call it wherever you need it (without going to the database).

This seems to me a lot harder to achieve in Asp.Net Core. What I have so far is:

ApplicationUser class:

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IIdentity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Uporabnik Uporabnik { get; set; }

    public string AuthenticationType { get; set; }
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Login form:

```cs
public IActionResult Prijava(PrijavaModel model)
{
    // check user credentials
    //
    //      ... validation code here ...
    //

    if (uporabnik != null)
    {
        //Create the identity for the user
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
        new Claim("Email", model.Email),
        new Claim("Id", uporabnik.IdWebUser.ToString()),
        new Claim("Name", uporabnik.ImeInPriimek),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, uporabnik.ImeInPriimek),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid, uporabnik.IdWebUser.ToString())
    }, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        var login = HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return View();
}
```

Now to retrieve the data in a controller I have to do something like this:

```cs
// id
int idUser = int.Parse(@User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "Id").Value);

// or email
string email = @User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "Email").Value;
```

Well, this all works fine, but it's definitely not practical. To access any other user data I can go to the database (by "ID") and retrieve it, but I don't think this is the right way to do it!?!

Can I expand the identity class in such a way that I can set the extra properties I need at login time and retrive in a fashion similar to something like this:

```cs
var property1 = @User.Property1;
var property2 = @User.Property2;

// or
var property1 = @User.MyExtraProperties.Property1;
var property2 = @User.MyExtraProperties.Property2;
```

Is it possible (and also keeping it simple)?

EDIT: since there are no answers/suggestions, can I do the same thing with a different approach?

Comment: Is this not possible?

Comment: You can add whichever claims you want to a user. i dont see the actual issue. e.g: `new Claim("birthdate", uporabnik.BirthDate.ToString()),`

Comment: @Dementic: because then I cannot call it like in my question: for example `@User.BirthDate`, but I have to get it like this `string birthdate= @User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "BirthDate").Value` and then cast it to DateTime. Also I cannot save a more complex property (for example an object with multiple properties/methods) in a way you are proposing...

Comment: you are too used to sessions. there is nothing wrong in doing a db call to get properties which should NOT exist until actualy needed. without a session (even with it) a user that was disabled/removed will still have access.

Comment: so doing a DB call in each (where user info is needed) Controller Action is the best way to tackle this issue (best practice)?

Comment: it would have been best if you followed the new methods of authentication. have you try to create .net core app from the provided templates (with autentication) and see how they handle the data and user?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I cant, I'm limited to using existing tables from our current (working) project

Comment: we'll do it with DB calls then

Comment: You could do with your own tables https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 0):

Look like you only want to call your properties in a better way?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string CustomName { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming you have done adding your extra properties, you could create an extension method for your properties, so you can later call them like `User.Identity.GetCustomName()`.

```
namespace Project.Extensions
{
    public static class IdentityExtensions
    {
        public static string GetCustomName(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("CustomName");
            return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I didn't include the part where you add the claims, because you already have it. In this case, you should have `CustomName` claim.

Also, @Dementic is right about the session. If a user is removed/disabled, he would still have access to. So, having a db call each time you need to fetch information is correct.

Comment: this way I still only get strings, not classes

Comment: in theory, if using this method, you could have a property that is serialized/desiarlized when called (JSON String). i would still recommend to go the "newer" way of authenticating.